# Petition to reopen a temporarily closed question from 2014

Tags: discussion

I'd like to petition for reopening of the question [Was there an electoral fraud during the referendum for the independance of Scotland?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/23287/was-there-an-electoral-fraud-during-the-referendum-for-the-independance-of-scotl) which was *temporarily* closed. A [comment](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/23287/was-there-an-electoral-fraud-during-the-referendum-for-the-independance-of-scotl?rq=1#comment89827_23287) from a diamond-mod states the reason for closing:

> Closing this temporarily until 1. the claim is shown to be notable (or not) and 2. the dust has settled and we can access eventual real, conclusive evidence. – Sklivvz♦ Sep 22 '14 at 0:01

I think both criteria are now fulfilled.

1. The claim has been brought up by both [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2014/sep/22/scottish-referendum-vote-rigging-claims-recount-petitions) and by [BBC](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-scotland-scotland-politics-29264151) so it should be notable.
2. It's been over four years since the event so the dust has definitely settled.

Comment: It's reopened now. I for one thought the question was clear enough even though it may have mixed some "incidents"/claims. The reason it seemed clear enough is that most sources addressed all those (early) "incidents"/claims in one article.

Answer (score 5):

I agree in principle to reopen, however the question as written does not represent the claim, but it looks like the OPs research. Clearly reopening as is would be problematic.

Let's reopen but fix the question first by citing an actually notable version of the claim.

Answer (score 4):

I am wrestling with this one.

Before we open it, should we now update it with the latest versions of the claim?

For example, you cite [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2014/sep/22/scottish-referendum-vote-rigging-claims-recount-petitions) on Sep 22, 2014, but by [2017](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2017/dec/13/russian-cyber-activists-tried-to-discredit-scottish-independence-vote-says-analyst) the discussion has moved on:

> An expert in Russian cyber-operations has accused Russian activists of running a disinformation campaign to discredit the Scottish independence referendum result, by wrongly alleging it was rigged.
>
> [...]
>
> The Electoral Commission, the UK authority that oversees elections and referendums, ruled the event was fair and could find no evidence of fraud in any counts, and nor did the police.

*I don't endorse this expert's speculations. I am just showing that readers of The Guardian may well have changed their understanding since 2014.*

Maybe I am getting off track here. Taking it back to first principles, rather than rely on a 2014 article for notability, we should be sure there is *still* a widely-believed claim.

The same 2017 article states:

> Its voter research did, however, uncover evidence that Scottish voters were more suspicious of this event than previously seen in the UK. It said 42% of yes voters thought fraud took place, compared with 21% of no voters.

So, I am comfortably there is a widely believed claim, but would you like to put some more up-to-date examples in the question before we re-open?